# OpenCV convolution kernel size

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

This is somewhat of a follow up to a question posted earlier last month.
In porting my work, to the work computer, I'm experiencing some new convolution problem.

So, my kernel is 30x30 size and now OpenCV complains:

```
Assertion failed (templ.cols <= 17 && templ.rows <= 17) in convolve, file /home/jeffrey/opencv/src/modules/gpu/src/imgproc.cpp, line 1677
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

So far this is the only noticeable problem I'm getting with the port so far..

Is this new, is this normal?

i'm also getting 2 errors which are most likely unrelated, but worth mentioning

```
[swscaler @ 0x9422b00]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
```

This is likely ffmpeg error

but i'm also getting an error stating OpenGL version unsupported

Could this be the culprit?

Comment: What is the message inside the cv::Exception that is being thrown?

Comment: Ok, I believe the HAVE_CUFFT check fails, I will rebuild OpenCV tomorrow ensuring the inclusion of this flag. Thanks charlie for the reply

Comment: @jeffricoelexotico If that is the answer, it's probably best to post it as an answer and accept it. Although, I understand you may not have all of the privileges yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was simply a lack of CUFFT
Thank you